# Problem with font on the first time load page

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hello everybody!**
I just learned html,css and javascript for over a month.
I had a problem when i used canvas to draw a text with custom font.
Font didn't load on the first time i run the code. But after that everything was ok.
I don't understand the reason why and i couldn't fix it.
Could anyone please tell me about the problem and the solution? Thank you.
Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        @font-face { font-family: SuperLegendBoy; src: url('SuperLegendBoy-4w8Y.ttf'); }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvass" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
<script>
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvass");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    function drawText() {
        ctx.font = "25px SuperLegendBoy";
        ctx.fillText("hello", 200, 200);

    }
    drawText();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

font-face can be very specific at times. Have you tried adding `format("truetype");` to the end of the font-face "src" style property?

Answer (score 0):

### What's the problem?

The problem is, that loading the font isn't synchronous. That is, it's started when the CSS `@font-face` at-rule is processed, however, it loads in the background. Then, when loaded, it re-styles all texts that use the font.

That wouldn't cause a problem in itself, but a `<canvas>` turns the text into pixel data immediately, so, when the font is loaded, it cannot be restyled.

### Why did it work for the second time?

Because browsers cache resources, and stores the font, so that it doesn't have to be downloaded again. Instead, loads the cached version, that is available immediately.

### How to solve it?

Wrap your JS that draws on the canvas in an `onload` event listener, that waits until all resources (including fonts) have loaded:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        @font-face { font-family: SuperLegendBoy; src: url('SuperLegendBoy-4w8Y.ttf'); }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvass" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
<script>
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvass");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    function drawText() {
        ctx.font = "25px SuperLegendBoy";
        ctx.fillText("hello", 200, 200);

    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        drawText();
    })

</script>
<!-- I think you've placed the closing body and html tags a bit early (it won't cause problems, though, as browsers wink at invalid HTML :)... It's enough to put the script as the last element of body. Or, even better, use the DOMContentLoaded event -->
</body>
</html>
```